# Passing multiple arguments with delete Request HTTP angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, angular-fullstack

I'm working with Angular 9 and Spring boot, i want to make delete request HTTP that delete multiple users.
 for one user it is easy by passing the id with the url ("localhost:8080/myApi/delete/1")
but for multiple users i dont know how to do

Comment: use FormData. see first anwser of this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59153634/send-list-of-int-in-angular-formdata-to-post-web-api-in-c-sharp

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55515105/rest-delete-multiple-items-in-the-batch